# carriage return c++ \r and \b output

Tags: c++, carriage-return

Can someone explain the below output.

I can't figure out why the output of the following statements:

```
printf("\n Hello");
printf("\b world");
printf("\r Cup");
```

is:

```
 Cupl world
```

Answer (score 3):

Lets use `|` as carriage:

After "\n": `|`

After " Hello": `Hello|`

After "\b": `Hell|`

After " world": `Hell world|`

After "\r": `| Hell world`

After " Cup": `Cup|l world`